# How does Python's unittest module detect test cases?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I was wondering when we run `unittest.main()`, how does Python know what subclasses `unittest.Testcase` has?

For example, if I add a class `FromRomanBadInput(unittest.TestCase)`, how does `unittest` know to run this?

Comment: Metaclasses are cool things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python

Comment: @Amber What do you mean? `unittest` has no single metaclass.

Comment: Just pointing out that metaclasses are one way to implement detection of what is sub-classing a given class.

Comment: @Amber It's not what they use, but it might be cleaner if they did.

Answer (score 33):

So I looked around in my `Python27/Lib` directory...

`unittest.main` is actually an alias for a class, `unittest.TestProgram`. So what happens is you construct an instance of this, and its `__init__` runs, which does a bunch of sanity checks and configuration, including a dynamic import of the module that you called it from (it uses the `__import__` function, with `__main__` as the name of the module to import, by default). So now it has a `self.module` attribute that contains a module object that represents your source.

Eventually, it gets to this code:

```
self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromModule(self.module)
```

where `self.testLoader` is an instance of `unittest.TestLoader`. That method contains, among other stuff:

```
    for name in dir(module):
        obj = getattr(module, name)
        if isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, case.TestCase):
            tests.append(self.loadTestsFromTestCase(obj))
```

So it uses the `dir` of your module object to get the names of all the global variables you defined (including classes), filters that to just the classes that derive from `unittest.TestCase` (locally, `case.TestCase` is an alias for that), and then looks for test methods inside those classes to add to the `tests` list. That search behaves similarly:

```
    def isTestMethod(attrname, testCaseClass=testCaseClass,
                     prefix=self.testMethodPrefix):
        return attrname.startswith(prefix) and \
            hasattr(getattr(testCaseClass, attrname), '__call__')
    testFnNames = filter(isTestMethod, dir(testCaseClass))
```

so it uses the `dir` of the class to get a list of names to try, looks for attributes with those names, and selects those that start with the `self.testMethodPrefix` (`'test'` by default) and that are callable (have, in turn, a `__call__` attribute). (I'm actually surprised they don't use the built-in `callable` function here. I guess this is to avoid picking up nested classes.)

Comment: Wow. That is really comprehensive and helpful. Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Comprehensive, maybe, but I can't really imagine how it's **helpful**. The documentation already tells you how to **use** `unittest`, which should be all you really need to know.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Well, it just so happened that you actually **helped** me with this answer. :) I wrote a decorator for unit tests and whole test cases and was wondering why the test runner wouldn't execute decorated test cases. Running the code above, I realized I forgot that my decorator (without arguments) turns my unittest.TestCase subclass into a completely different object…

Comment: Here's the `Lib/unittest/` source: https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/unittest

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It helped me because I was trying to add test cases dynamically, assuming that nose created an instance of the unittest.TestCase classes I had, i.e. that it calls __init__ on my test classes. It does not, it examines the classes directly. So it helps me too.

Comment: Another use was that it satisfied my curiosity.

Comment: @Joel Could you solve that? I am trying to do the same, but tests are not loaded. Here is my question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/68013492/1312850

Answer (score 7):

the 'main' function searches for all classes which inherits the unittest.TestCase in imported modules. and current path, then tries to run each method that starts with 'test'

from [python's document](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html):

```
import random
import unittest

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = range(10)

    def test_shuffle(self):
        # make sure the shuffled sequence does not lose any elements
        random.shuffle(self.seq)
        self.seq.sort()
        self.assertEqual(self.seq, range(10))

        # should raise an exception for an immutable sequence
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, random.shuffle, (1,2,3))

    def test_choice(self):
        element = random.choice(self.seq)
        self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

    def test_sample(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            random.sample(self.seq, 20)
        for element in random.sample(self.seq, 5):
            self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

> A testcase is created by subclassing unittest.TestCase. The three
>   individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the
>   letters test. This naming convention informs the test runner about
>   which methods represent tests.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some code that attempts to do behave similarly to unittest.main() below. In summary, I iterate through the modules, and for the modules that don't start with the name 'unittest', I inspect its members. Then if those members is a class and is a subclass of unittest.TestCase, I parse through that class' members. Then if those class' members is a function or method that starts with 'test', I add it to the list of tests. The class object's `__dict__` is used to introspect the methods/functions since using inspect.getmembers may show too much. Finally that list of tests is converted to a tuple and wrapped up as a suite. Then the suite is ran using the runner at verbosity level 2. Note that, of course, removing the regex that checks for 'test' at the beginning of a function/method name can be removed to include bar_test() to the list of tests if you don't want that restriction.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
import inspect
import sys
import re

class Foo(unittest.TestCase):
   @staticmethod
   def test_baz():
      pass

   @classmethod
   def test_mu(cls):
      pass

   def test_foo(self):
      self.assertEqual('foo', 'foo')

   def bar_test(self):
      self.assertEqual('bar', 'bar')

class Bar:
   pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
   runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
   tests = []
   is_member_valid_test_class = lambda member: inspect.isclass(member) and \
      issubclass(member, unittest.TestCase)

   for module_name, module_obj in sys.modules.items():
      if not re.match(r'unittest', module_name):
         for cls_name, cls in inspect.getmembers(
            module_obj, is_member_valid_test_class):
            for methname, methobj in cls.__dict__.items():
               if inspect.isroutine(methobj) and re.match(r'test', methname):
                  tests.append(cls(methname))

   suite = unittest.TestSuite(tests=tuple(tests))
   runner.run(suite)
```

The resulting output is:

```
test_foo (__main__.Foo) ... ok
test_baz (__main__.Foo) ... ok
test_mu (__main__.Foo) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

OK
```