# Running all selenium tests inside a test case

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have multiple tests inside one test case but I am noticing that it is only running the first test

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.base_url = "http://www.example.com/"
    def test_Google(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.get(self.base_url)
    def fill_contact(self):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(.,"Contact")]').click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"][@value="Send"]').click()

    # def tearDown(self):
    #     self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Whenever I run this it only runs

```
def test_Google(self)
```

and nothing after that. am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods must begin with `'test'` to be automatically run.

[Per the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example):

> A testcase is created by subclassing unittest.TestCase. The three
>   individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the
>   letters `test`. **This naming convention informs the test runner about
>   which methods represent tests.** (my emphasis)

---

The `TestLoader` is responsible for loading test and returning them wrapped in a `TestSuite`. It uses [this method to identify tests](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ac176a69d188/Lib/unittest/loader.py#l214):

```
class TestLoader(object):
    testMethodPrefix = 'test'
    def getTestCaseNames(self, testCaseClass):
        """Return a sorted sequence of method names found within testCaseClass
        """
        def isTestMethod(attrname, testCaseClass=testCaseClass,
                         prefix=self.testMethodPrefix):
            return attrname.startswith(prefix) and \
                hasattr(getattr(testCaseClass, attrname), '__call__')
        testFnNames = filter(isTestMethod, dir(testCaseClass))
        ...
```

Thus, the `attrname.startswith(prefix)` checks if the method name begins with `'test'`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to what @unubtu noted:

you can use a [`nose` test runner](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and mark a method with [`@istest` decorator](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.istest):

```
from nose.tools import istest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

    @istest
    def fill_contact(self):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(.,"Contact")]').click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"][@value="Send"]').click()
```

Besides, here is a pretty good overview of the `unittest` test discovery:

- [How does Python's unittest module detect test cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099491/how-does-pythons-unittest-module-detect-test-cases)